# Where is 'With' method defined. ReactiveUI

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

I saw [here](http://reactiveui.readthedocs.org/en/stable/basics/schedulers/) that we can use

```
 (new TestScheduler()).With(sched =>{
    // Code run in this block will have both RxApp.MainThreadScheduler
    // and RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler assigned to the new TestScheduler.
});
```

But where is `With` method defined. I cant find any. Please help.

`Microsoft.Reactive.Testing.TestScheduler` does not contain a definition for `With` and no extension method `With` accepting a first argument of type `Microsoft.Reactive.Testing.TestScheduler` could be found

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension method defined [here](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI.Testing/TestUtils.cs#L109) and you need nuget package [reactiveui-testing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/reactiveui-testing/) to have it available.